# Need help adding two DWORDLONG's together

Tags: c++

Im trying to code a trainer for one of my games, usually this isnt a problem for me, however the game runs on 64-bit.

My problem is that i try to add an Offset to my baseadress (DWORDLONG += DWORD), however i dont get a DWORDLONG returned but rather a DWORD, so i lose the Adress.

Im Expecting 0x0000a7b335d97314
But im getting 0x0000000300905a4d

I already tried to:
Change the offset datatype to DWORD and DWORDLONG.
Using (DWORDLONG) in the addision.
Googeling my problem..

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use `std::ptrdiff_t` to add pointer types. If you can't for whatever reason, then cast the `DWORD` to `DWORDLONG` then add it.. so: `myDwordLong += static_cast<DWORDLONG>(myDword);`

Comment: Can you show us the line that's not working as you expect? Adding an int to a long int should yield a long int without any casting required.

Comment: @Brandon I'll try that thank you.

Comment: @Cameron im simply doing this:  Adress = Adress + Offset0;

Comment: This is weird because even if the result was somehow being cast to a `DWORD`, the lower 32 bits should be correct -- however the lower 32 bits of your "expected" value are different than your "getting" value.  So I think the problem is something else.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles Well i experiment a bit and the problem must be the adding, because the adress is valid till that point.

Comment: You need to show us the real code, because from your description, the code should work fine.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles

`DWORDLONG GameHacking::getAdress(DWORDLONG BaseAdress, DWORD Offset0, DWORD Offset1, DWORD Offset2, DWORD Offset3, DWORD Offset4, HANDLE PHANDLE) //Gets base adress
{
 DWORDLONG Adress;
 ReadProcessMemory(PHANDLE, (LPCVOID)BaseAdress, &Adress, sizeof(DWORDLONG), NULL);

 if (Offset0 != NULL)
 {
  Adress += Offset0;
 };
 if (Offset1 != NULL)
 {
  ReadProcessMemory(PHANDLE, (LPCVOID)BaseAdress, &Adress, sizeof(DWORDLONG), NULL);
  Adress += Offset1;
 };
 };
return Adress;
}`

Comment: please edit the question and put your code there, code in comments is barely readable

Comment: @KarstenKoop better Idea: https://pastebin.com/VGNBuJ2s